# Android onclick Buttons Sequence

Tags: android, onclick, sequence, onclicklistener

I have 5 buttons every one has letter (Button "H",Button "E"Button "L"Button "L"Button "O") which make the word "HELLO". what I need is to make on click sequence to these buttons so if I click "H" first and "E" second until complete the word the app will do something, But if I click "L" first will give me some error message.

Any Idea to do this sequence?

Thanks

Comment: so, what have you tried?

Comment: Well, I'm still thinking how to do this :(

Comment: I'll give you a suggestion then. Try it out and come back here, if you're stuck up anywhere. "On every button's `click`, do 2 things, first, check if the previous button to be **clicked** is `clicked`, and next, set a flag for this button as `clicked` or not `notclicked` based on the above **condition**".

Comment: thanks, nice idea. But I don't know how to check if the previous button was clicked or not:((, I kind of new in android and java. If you can give me an example for 2 buttons that will be really great. thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just have an Array like this:

```
int[] tracker = new int[5];
```

and when you click a button, say "H", set `tracker[0] = 1;`

but when you click a button, say "L", check whether all the previous button values are `1`. If yes, then set the corresponding tracker to `1` else, show an error message, and do not make any change to the tracker Array.

**Something Like this:**

```
onHClick{

tracker[0] = 1;
}

onEClick{

for(int i=0; i<1; i++){
if(tracker[i] == 0){    
//show error message and return;
}else{
tracker[1] = 1;
return;
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly your flow but you can try this.

1. set Tag to each button as its Text, like this.

   b.setTag("H");

and than after like this.

```
Button b;
String name = "";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String s = (String) v.getTag();

            name +=s;

                          if( "HELLO".startsWith(name)){
                                  <VALID>
                          }else{
                                  <ERROR>
                          }   
        }
    });

}
```

check the variable `name` on each button click with your original word i.e. `HELLO` like above.

Comment: Thank you, The problem that this method will check after you complete typing, but as I asked in my question that if you click L first an error message or something will happen also if you click H then click O will give you the same error message. I think I just need to know How to flag any button after i clicked. If you can help me with that will be great.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

When activity started you just make other button `Enabled = false` of something like that. But make the first button Enabled. **Don't** make the `Visible=false`.

Now on click of Button "H" make enable Button "E" and so on.

So user will only have to click the button in sequence. Button can not be presses in any random manner.

Try this and let me know that it works or not.

Answer (score 1):

Very Interesting and exactly same to your requirement..check once..

If you give any string other than `HELLO` also works better.

```
public class ButtonTest extends Activity
{
    private String result="";
    String sampleText   =   "HELLO";

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);

        int noOfBtns        =   sampleText.length();

        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.btnlay);
        final TextView tvtext = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);

        final Button[] btns     =   new Button[noOfBtns];

        for(int i=0;i<noOfBtns;i++)
        {
            btns[i] =   new Button(this);
            btns[i].setText(sampleText.substring(i,i+1));

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            ll.addView(btns[i], lp);

            final int j = i;
            btns[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    System.out.println(j+" "+result.length());
                    if(j == result.length())
                    {
                        result = result+btns[j].getText().toString();

                        if(sampleText.startsWith(result))
                        {
                            tvtext.setText(result);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong Button Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/result"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"/>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/btnlay"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
package com.example.buttonsequence;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{   

    ArrayList<Button> buttonList=null;
    TextView resultTextView=null;
    Button buttons[]=null;
    String helloStr="HELLO";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        buttonList=new ArrayList<Button>();
        buttons=new Button[5];

        this.resultTextView=(TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.result_text);
        this.resultTextView.setText("");

        buttons[0]=(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.h_button);
        buttons[1]=(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.e_button);
        buttons[2]=(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.l_button);
        buttons[3]=(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.l2_button);
        buttons[4]=(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.o_button);

        for(int k=0;k<5;k++)
            buttons[k].setOnClickListener(onClickListener);

        Button button=(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.exit_button);
        button.setOnClickListener
        (
                new OnClickListener()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        finish();
                    }

                }
        );
    }

    OnClickListener onClickListener=new OnClickListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Button b=(Button)v;
            buttonList.add(b);

            int size=buttonList.size();
            if(size>0)
            {
                StringBuilder resultBuilder=new StringBuilder();
                for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
                {
                    Button tempButton=buttonList.get(i);
                    if(tempButton==buttons[i])
                    {
                        resultBuilder.append(helloStr.charAt(i));

                        if(i==4)
                        {
                            resultTextView.setText(resultBuilder.toString()+" clicked");
                            buttonList.clear();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            resultTextView.setText(resultBuilder.toString()+" clicked");
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        buttonList.remove(i);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No correctly clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                resultTextView.setText("Invalid pressed");
            }

        }

    };




}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/h_button"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="H" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/e_button"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="E" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/l_button"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="L" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/l2_button"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="L" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/o_button"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="O" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/result_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/exit_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Exit" />

</LinearLayout>
```